# open one out of browser from another for silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have two fully trusted out of browser applications.

What i want is to be in one and a user clicks a button and that opens the second silverlight oob application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pinvoke and sllauncher contain the answer that you seek.